# Markers not showing in Google Maps - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm struggling with the markers... I'm trying to show a marker on click in my local XAMPP server. In the HTML I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=TRUE">
</script>

<div id="map" class="centered row clearfix partida doesntPlay"></div>
```

And then in the JS:

```
var marker;
var markers = [];

var initialize = function() {

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.177644, -2.310920),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
});
}
// Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
map: map
});
markers.push(marker);
console.log("new Marker: " + marker.getPosition().k + "/" +marker.getPosition().D);
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setAllMap(map) {
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
markers[i].setMap(map);
}
}

// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
setAllMap(null);
}

// Shows any markers currently in the array.
function showMarkers() {
setAllMap(map);
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
clearMarkers();
 markers = [];
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have to say that the map is hidden and when the users click a button it appears. I've tried it with a displaying map and got the same results. I can see the log on the console with the latitude and longitude, but the map is not showing any marker.

Can somebody help me?

EDIT:

I noticed that if I comment the line of Bootstrap CSS the markers appear perfectly. So the problem is that there are in the map, but not showing because of CSS. Anyhow, I cannot see the markers yet.

RE-EDIT:

SOLVED (more or less). If I use a custom icon, no problem. So I use as customo icon the default icon, and done.

Comment: [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/a3DC6/28/). The only difference between your code and my example is that I added width and height attributes to the map element.

Comment: It's not working on my page. I'm using bootstrap and I noticed that if I disable Bootstrap CSS it's working. Now I'm trying to disable the styles affecting to the markers.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (more or less). If I use a custom icon, no problem. So I use as custom icon the default icon, and done.